# PHP if else with database

Tags: php

I'm having a trouble with my php file. I've done a connection to my database so I can check something about it.

I've got an IF-ELSE statement to do something in case the return of the database is what I wanted. The thing is everytime I reload the url, I get the echo in the ELSE statement, instead of nothing. I dont want the IF-ELSE to execute until I submit a html form I've got.

Here is a simple example:

```
if($somethingToCheck){
   echo 'hey!';
}else{ echo 'BAD!'; }
```

The var $somethingToCheck is declared and I know is right.

So as I explained, if I reload the url, I will get the string BAD! in my screen, even if I have not submited my form.

There's a way to NOT EXECUTE that IF-ELSE statement until I submit my html form?

EDIT: more details about my problem.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve...If that is at the top of your script, when it loads, $somethingToCheck will be undefined, so will always be false.

Comment: I seems to me that you have a problem understanding how exactly PHP works (as far as such a conclusion is possible from your question). This, however, makes it extremely difficult to figure out what your problem actually is, because most of us probably don't even get to that point. :) Provide more information about your problem, especially the full piece of code that is causing problems.

Comment: `var_dump($somethingToCheck)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose it in a block that only is runned when answering to a post:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if($somethingToCheck){
       echo 'hey!';
    }else{ echo 'BAD!'; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what I needed. Now it wont show any message until I submit my html form.

Answer (score 0):

Check if ther is a posted data

```
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            if($somethingToCheck){
                echo 'hey!';
            }else{
                echo 'BAD!';
            }
        }
```